# GIMP. TIFF. Color profile sRGB IEC61966-2.1 and embedded color profile GIMP - built-in sRGB

Tags: gimp, tiff

Friend gave me photos. TIFF with LZW compression. Parks, people walking, relaxing. People are doing fitness. I want to crop these TIFFs, resize. Then I will export it to JPEG. Then I will post these JPEGs on my blog.

I run Windows 10 Home 64-bit. GIMP 2.10.

I opening TIFF in GIMP. GIMP says:

The image has an embedded color profile sRGB IEC61966-2.1

Convert the image to the built-in sRGB color profile?

Rendering intent: Relative colorimetric.

Black Point Compensation. Flag is on.

Button Convert. Button Keep.

How do I respond to this GIMP question?

Comment: "How do I respond to this GIMP question?" – Flip a coin. It makes no difference at all.

Answer (score 4):

Don't convert - at all.

At import tell it not to convert.
At export tell it not to convert.

sRGB IEC61966-2.1 is "industry standard" RGB used for the web.
Any time you do colour-space conversion you potentially change the colour balance. If you don't have a fully calibrated system this can make changes you can't even see or know about. Preserving standard sRGB throughout means less margin for error.

Comment: Converting from sRGB to sRGB should make no difference.

Comment: Converting to "built-in sRGB color profile" could make a lot of difference, as we have no clue what that profile is. Leaving it completely alone is always going to be a better strategy.

Comment: GIMP built-in sRGB is functionally identical to [`sRGB2014.icc`](http://www.color.org/profiles/sRGB2014.icc) from the International Color Consortium. Applying and converting each profile in sequence results in *no* change to the image data (identical `md5` hash).

Comment: I'm not sure why you're building such a defence of "converting to the same thing" when the simplest way to be certain is to not convert if you don't have to.

Comment: You claim "could make a lot of difference" – in fact, it makes no difference at all. Any *potential* change from sRGB to sRGB would be dwarfed by the resize operation OP intends to perform.

Comment: Do you want to spend the next 24 hours also researching whether Rendering Intent and Black-point Compensation will also leave it unchanged… or perhaps consider just not converting at all would be a whole lot simpler?

Comment: Your process is fine if you need every bit perfect. But in that case, you wouldn't be resizing and saving to JPEG. For OP's purposes, it makes no difference.

Comment: You still seem to be expending a lot of energy defending a process which is completely & utterly unnecessary. I'm not sure whey that is. I'm done with this pointless back & forth now.

Comment: Your recommendation is simply paranoid. An identity operation may be wasted cpu cycles, but the output is still equivalent to a noop.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it makes little to no difference, since you would be converting from sRGB to sRGB. At most, you would see a few insignificant-bit flips. (Note: *insignificant bit* is a technical term.)

If the input file had a different profile, like Adobe RGB, you *should* convert to sRGB since you plan to use the images on the web.

*Do* save copies of the unmodified original files.

---

To demonstrate there is no significant difference:

- Since I do not have copies of your images, I obtained the sRGB v2 color profile from the International Color Consortium website (`sRGB2014.icc`).

  - [sRGB profiles](http://www.color.org/srgbprofiles.xalter)

  I chose this file because the profile you are using says *-2.1*. There are other versions that may give different results.
- Then I generated a Hald-12 image with ImageMagick. Each pixel in a Hald image is a different color, arranged in a pattern that can used to apply color corrections via lookup table.

  ```
  convert hald:12 hald12-0.png
  ```
- Using GIMP, I exported to the `png` to `hald12-1.bmp`, making sure to check "Do not write colorspace information".
- Assigned the color profile `sRGB2014.icc` to the image.
- Converted to the GIMP built-in sRGB profile.
- Exported the result to `hald12-2.bmp`.
- Compared results with `md5sum`.  In this case, the conversion resulted in *no* difference.

  ```
  64869fef4a0acf95bea03369d5a89149  hald12-0.png
  6a083813783d9f99a0918c3d97e2364b  hald12-1.bmp
  6a083813783d9f99a0918c3d97e2364b  hald12-2.bmp
  ```

Comment: I'd still always recommend only ever converting at export. Personally I work at Adobe RGB right through from camera, which gives me the option of still having it available later if needed. One quick 'throwaway' conversion to sRGB at export & my original is safe.

Comment: Adobe RGB has slightly wider gamut, so there is increased risk of banding.  OP appears to be doing simple edits to prep for web, so conversion at import would be fine.

Comment: …but he's not converting from Adobe, he's converting from one defined sRGB to another ill-defined. Therefore, don't convert at all.

Comment: That's why that sentence starts with *If*.  It's possible there are images with other profiles in the collection that OP hasn't encountered *yet*.  Also, GIMP is only reporting what the profile claims to be.  Without examining the profile more closely, it's not certain that it really is what it says.  You put more trust in the embedded profile... I think it doesn't matter... but if pressed, I'd trust the GIMP profile over one with unknown source.

Comment: Well… if the embedded profile is unreliable… & the built-in profile is an unknown… it would make even less sense to play with it. Worst-case scenario for converting to any profile at import is that the user, in a 'little knowledge is a dangerous thing' kind of way, had a screen profile set somewhere in colour prefs. I've seen plenty of people do it in Photoshop without knowing how much it messes up their colour workflow.

Comment: The final destination is web.  So it is appropriate to convert to sRGB.

Comment: It is never appropriate to convert if you don't have to.